# WinForms Map location coordinates

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, api, google-maps

when the form loads user needs to enter street and city. After that I need to show him that location on the map and also to save longitude and latitude of that address.

I've done only this, which finds the location of the street and I can display it on the form(but it's ugly,if you have better solution please share). But I don't know how to get coordinates of that location.

```
StringBuilder queryAddress = new StringBuilder();
                queryAddress.Append("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=");
                queryAddress.Append(street + "," + "+");
                queryAddress.Append(city);
                webBrowser1.Navigate(queryAddress.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is known as [Geocoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding), getting coordinates based on address.

Google has a Geocoding API, which has a really nice documentation [**here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro).
I recommend you to read it thoroughly, and I will summarize the crux of the approach:

You can use Google's Geocoding API over HTTP(S) like this:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/outputFormat?parameters

where **output** is json/xml and **paramaters** can vary, but the simples form is **address** like in your example above and a mandatory Google's API **[key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key)**.

Example:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: I'm not that experienced programmer, actually I don't know how to call that and where to store that json so that I can read from it, I tried something but I get this message.                                                                            {
   "error_message" : "This API project was not found. This API project may have been deleted.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Comment: @I.pattern Maybe Google requires Billing for that particular API. You should read the documentation provided in the links in the answer.

Comment: @I.Pattern Also, a bonus. If you check out URL in regular browser after you go to `http://maps.google.com/maps?q=street,city` like you do in your code, you will see that Google appends the coordinates there. Maybe you can recreate that in your application.

Comment: @I.pattern If my answer has helped you please mark it as answered